# CollectionView in C# without XAML, Binding problems

Tags: c#, .net, collectionview, maui

I spend two days on MS Documentation and on Google but no luck so far... I am trying to create a new MAUI App with no XAML (kind of an academic approach to understand what happens under the hood). Unfortunately - understandable - there is only very limited documentation for this approach and literally no samples omitting XAML.

Here is where I am stuck:

**I have a `ContentPage` that holds, among others, a `CollectionView`:**

```
public partial class AppPage : ContentPage
    {
        CollectionView baseListView;
[...]
        public AppPage()
        {
            this.BindingContext = new ViewModels.AppPageVM();
[...]
            baseListView = new CollectionView();
            baseListView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "BaseList.Bases"); 
            baseListView.EmptyView = "No Data!";
            baseListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                VerticalStackLayout view = new();
                var titleLabel = new Label
                {
                    FontSize = 14
                };

                titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");
                view.Children.Add(titleLabel);

                return new ViewCell { View = view };
            });
            myStackLayout.Children.Add(baseListView);
[...]
        }
    }
```

**As you can see `ContentPage` creates the `ViewModel` as its `BindingContext`. The ViewModel inherits from `BaseViewModel : ObservableObject` and uses `ComunityToolkit.MVVM.ComponentModel` to make BaseList public:**

```
public partial class AppPageVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        Models.TOBaseList baseList = new Models.TOBaseList();

        public AppPageVM()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

**that holds the supposed List Content in an `ObservableCollection` published as `Bases`:**

```
public partial class TOBaseList : BaseModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<TOBase> bases;

        public TOBaseList(string file = "tobasen.json")
        {
            ReadBasesFromJson(file);  //validated and contains more than 100 items)
        }
   [...]
```

**I get the most beloved: `System.NullReferenceException**

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Items.TemplatedCell.Bind(DataTemplate template, Object bindingContext, ItemsView itemsView)
```

I assume either a misunderstanding in creating the `ItemTemplate` or even messed up the whole ViewModel construct. Anyway, I can't get my head around it and find no samples in plain c# where this was solved.

Comment: `ViewCell` is not valid with `CollectionView`.  It is only used with `ListView`

Comment: Thanks for that hint @Jason – simply returning the `view` instead solved two frustrating days...

Comment: @Jason this should be answer here

Comment: Would have loved to mark it if it just was one to mark.